# How do I make an Android widget with scrollable text?

Tags: android, android-widget

I want to make a home screen widget with scrollable text but ScrollView is not allowed in a RemoteView. I know it must work somehow because there's this app that does it (https://michael-lin-sticky-note.de.aptoide.com/app) but I just can't get it to work.

Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, they use a `ListView`. `GridView` is also a scrollable container [available for `RemoteViews`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RemoteViews).

Using `ListView` and `GridView` is a bit complex — see [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/appwidgets/collections) for more.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, I'll try that